# Filter out lines that have a column of text begining at a particular column number

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file containing columnar data and I would like to filter out lines that meet a specific criteria: the data in the second-to-last column begins at column 161 rather than 162. So given this:

```
EP10101 12011   SC0     NCI Application Security                                    DLS3270 SC040P20Maintain User Access                                        MF20170901150328000NGS2    20170901150328000            
EP10101 12011   SC0     NCI Application Security                                    DLS3270 SC040P20Maintain User Access                                        PF20170901150328000NGS2    20170901150328000            
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS20P10RDR Maintenance                                              B20171016171130000NGS2    20171016171130000            
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS07P10NCFI Lease/Loan Payout Query                                 B20171016134250000NGS2    20171016134250000            
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS20P10RDR Maintenance                                              B20171016143354000NGS2    20171016143354000
```

I'm left with this after processing:

```
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS20P10RDR Maintenance                                              B20171016171130000NGS2    20171016171130000            
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS07P10NCFI Lease/Loan Payout Query                                 B20171016134250000NGS2    20171016134250000            
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS20P10RDR Maintenance                                              B20171016143354000NGS2    20171016143354000
```

How can I achieve this with command line tools?

**UPDATE**

I want to delete the lines with the matched pattern and also need to delete the last columns in the file. So my ultimate output should be like below.

```
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS20P10RDR Maintenance          
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS07P10NCFI Lease/Loan Payout Query
```

Comment: Are the lines wrapped like that, such that groups of them should go together?

Comment: In your example there is no line longer than 84 characters, and all lines have trailing spaces. Please post a real example.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. What is the criteria for lines to be deleted?

Comment: @αғsнιη I have posted some input data from the file in the question. IF you look at the last 2 columns in the data "MF20170901150328000NGS2"(161-184) and "B20171016171130000NGS2"(162-184). I need to delete the whole row from the file if i find any column with positions (161-184). In the above input which i mentioned in the question the first 2 lines needs to get deleted.Layer provided a solution to this. I need to include one more logic in which it should delete the last 2 columns from the entire file also. So finally i need to delete the complete line if it matches (161-184) position..contd

Comment: and also it needs to delete the last 2 columns from the entire file i.e (B20171016171130000NGS2    20171016171130000). Please let me know whether my requirement is clear or not. In my updated question i have provided the final ouput.

Comment: As I note in a comment below, the question was answered and the answer was accepted before the second requirement was submitted. The second requirement should be removed. Also, I've effectively answered the second part for you in a comment. You just need to expend a little effort to apply my input and you should have everything you need. Hint: look at the `-e` option to `sed` for a way to combine two directives in one `sed` call.

Comment: Alternatively, you can search this site for questions about removing columns like you want to do. One or both of these approaches should easily provide all of the information you need to address the added requirement.

Comment: Thanks Layer. I am going with 2 commands for this fix. 1) The sed option which you provided and 2) After modification in the above file i am using the below command to achieve my output. awk '{print substr($0,1,161)}'. Please let me know if this is an efficient approach to proceed?

Comment: Well, if you're not going to use `sed` for both then have a look at the `cut` command and the `-c` flag (which takes a range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a guess since the question is not entirely clear but

```
sed '/^.\{160\}\S\+/d' file
```

If this finds "data" (non-whitespace) at column 161 the line is deleted. All other lines are printed. This results in the output:

```
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS20P10RDR Maintenance                                              B20171016171130000NGS2    20171016171130000
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS07P10NCFI Lease/Loan Payout Query                                 B20171016134250000NGS2    20171016134250000
OS10101 12011   DLS     NCI Dealer Systems                                          DLS3270 DLS20P10RDR Maintenance                                              B20171016143354000NGS2    20171016143354000
```

(Can't help but think there is a better approach but this is all OP provides.)

Comment: Hi Layer. Is it possible to delete the last 2 columns if the same criteria matches?

Comment: You want something like this? `sed 's/^\(.\{160\}\S.*\)..$/\1/g' file`

Comment: Actually, maybe what you mean is to delete the entire column blocks rather than one-character wide columns like those we have been talking about. If so try this: `sed 's/^\(.\{160\}\)\S\+.*/\1/' file`

Comment: Thanks Layer. I got the correct scenario now. After successfully deleting the lines with the match i also need to delete the last columns in the file. So my ultimate output should be like I have edited the question.

Comment: @Layer Can you help on this one?

Comment: @RaviRock You aren't supposed to fundamentally change or add to a question after you've submitted it and people have offered answers. You could submit a new question but what you really should do is figure out how to do what you want based on the information you have already been given. It shouldn't be that hard. Note that there's an expectation at this site that people ask questions only after they've made a reasonable effort to figure it out themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Use below command as tested it worked fine

```
for i in $(awk '{if ((length($1) > "160") && (length($1) < "184"))print NR}' filename); do sed "$i"d p.txt; done
```

Comment: Why use `sed` if you’re already using `awk`?

Comment: @StephenKitt Its Just an alternative As we can achieve using both sed and awk

Comment: My point is that you can do the whole operation in AWK, no need to use `sed` in a loop afterwards.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes agree